# What are "Shrub Worms"?

Tags: max-axe

There's a mission goal to "wipe out 20 shrub worms in one game." It's only worth one point, so it shouldn't be hard.

I can't for the life of me figure out what a shrub worm is, and after playing a lot of games,** I've never had it tell me that I got more than 5 or so.  Clearly I need to target something specifically, but I have no clue what.

Where do they live and what do they look like?

** I sort of hate this game, but am engaged in a competition that I'd hate losing even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it's those tree looking thing that hide under shrubs and shoot balls at you (although they look like poison shooting trees to me.. )

Comment: You nailed it.  I was sure this was wrong when I read it, because the numbers seemed off from my tests, but I was lumping all things that shoot together, and some are those dragon things.